# Make column to always contain calculated value without triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I was doing practice tests before 70-461 exam and one of questions was to create table that:

- Has 4 columns, saleid, unitprice, amount, and price.
- Price is calculated by multiplication of unitprice and amount
- You can't use triggers.

The last one killed me. How can I do it without triggers? Here is my solutions using instead of triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE [HR].[Stuff](
    [saleid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [unitprice] [float] NOT NULL,
    [amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [calculate_price_insert]
ON [HR].[Stuff]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @unitprice float = (SELECT TOP 1 unitprice from inserted )
    DECLARE @amount float = (SELECT TOP 1 amount from inserted)
    INSERT INTO HR.[Stuff]
    VALUES(@unitprice,@amount, @unitprice*@amount)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [calculate_price_update]
ON [HR].[Stuff]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @unitprice float = (SELECT TOP 1 unitprice from inserted )
    DECLARE @amount float = (SELECT TOP 1 amount from inserted)
    UPDATE HR.[Stuff]
    SET unitprice = @unitprice, amount = @amount, price = @unitprice*@amount
    WHERE unitprice = (SELECT TOP 1 saleid from inserted)
GO
```

Comment: Why not create a view?

Comment: Because that was the task, to create a table like that =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE [HR].[Stuff](
    [saleid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [unitprice] [float] NOT NULL,
    [amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [price] AS ([unitprice] * [amount])
)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377127)**</kbd>

Also storing unitprice and amount as `FLOAT` may be dangerous because `FLOAT` isn't accurate datatype. Use `DECIMAL(12,4)` instead.

Your original trigger solution will fail, because trigger is executed per statement, not per row. Try with:

```
INSERT INTO [HR].[Stuff](unitprice, amount) VALUES (10, 20), (30, 50), (100,1);
```

You will loose records with `INSERT` and get false results with multiple `UPDATE`.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d158c/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @Skylerdw See my updated answer, especially about trigger part

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than I thought.